# Angular: Accessing a template reference variable located inside `async` pipe element

Tags: angular

I want to access a template reference variable using `@ViewChild` while the element is inside an element with `async` pipe present as follows:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="productTemplates$ | async as templates; else loading">
  <div class="row">
    <mat-checkbox #selectAll (change)="toggleAllTemplates($event)">Select All</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

How can I safely access the `#selectAll` reference early in the lifecycle of the component (like in `ngAfterViewInit`) while it is not present until the API call for products is returned?

Comment: You can't. 

View children are accessible when they exist. If they don't, then you can't get them before the condition is resolved. Could you tell us what is your goal, instead of asking for what you think is the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace the `@ViewChild` with `@ViewChildren` instead. It might seem not that intuitive at first, but the reasoning behind it is that `@ViewChildren` always returns you a `QueryList` that is not `null` inside the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle method.

You can then subscribe to the `changes` observable to be notified each time this query list changes

```js
@ViewChildren('selectAll', { read: MatCheckbox }) selectAllCheckboxes!: QueryList<MatCheckbox>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.selectAllCheckboxes.changes.pipe(
    filter(() => this.selectAllCheckboxes.length > 0)
  ).subscribe(() => this.doSomethingWithTheCheckbox());
}

private doSomethingWithTheCheckbox() {
  const selectAllCheckbox = this.selectAllCheckboxes.first;
  // here you should be able to safely use your selectAllCheckbox
}
```